# How do I move a QPixMapImage around a qgraphicsview

Tags: c++, qt4, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I can add a QPixMapImage to a QGraphicsScene, but then I have two issues.

First I cannot create a pointer to my QPixmapItem declared in the header, where i can with QGraphicsScene.

I get an error "error: no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsPixmapItem::QGraphicsPixmapItem(MainWindow* const)" ... When I create my QGraphicsScene in Main the same way?

Second issue: I cannot move the QGraphicsPixmapItem around when the slider is moved (obv i won't until the pointer is working).  But can I even move it, or do i have to repaint it?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPixmap>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QPixmap arrow = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage("ARROW.png"));
    arrowItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(this);
    arrowItem->setPixmap(arrow);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->horizontalSlider->setMaximum(2000);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    arrowItem->setPos(position,position);
    scene->addItem(arrowItem);

}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *arrowItem;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;

private slots:
    void on_horizontalSlider_sliderMoved(int position);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue #1:

There error you're getting means there is no such constructor declared for QGraphicsPixmapItem; you use either one of these:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0
#ifndef Q_QDOC
                        // ### obsolete argument
                        , QGraphicsScene *scene = 0
#endif
        );
    QGraphicsPixmapItem(const QPixmap &pixmap, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0
#ifndef Q_QDOC
                        // ### obsolete argument
                        , QGraphicsScene *scene = 0
#endif
        );
```

Issue#2

If I understood your question correctly you want to be able to drag your graphics items around the scene. You can switch this functionality on by using [view->setDragMode](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop) method.

Please see if an example below would work for you:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(QRect(-50, -50, 400, 200));

    QPixmap image = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage("image.JPG"));
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixMapItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
    pixMapItem->setPixmap(image);
    scene->addItem(pixMapItem);

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(ui->centralWidget);
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->setGeometry(QRect(50, 50, 400, 200));
    view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
    view->show();
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Actually I would like to move the pixmap by moving a slider as opposed to a mouse click... do you know how to do that?

Comment: by "slider" do you mean a QSlider or smth else?

Comment: Yes a QSlider, or a QScrollBar ... Thanks!

Comment: add an instance of QSlider to your window, connect to its sliderMoved signal. In the signal handler move your pixmap item by changing it's offset or pos property. slidermoved signal will provide you with current position of the slider.

Comment: Yes... I get that, I guess I still do not understand your solution to my original question 1.

Comment: hmm... did you give a try to the example I've provided; is it working for you? make QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixMapItem a member of your MainWindow class; after that you can reference it in the slider's sliderMoved signal

Comment: ugghhh i was doing this: arrowItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(this);
  it should have been arrowItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
  works now.... Thanks!!!